# UISplitView with toolbar/tabbar at bottom of detail view

Tags: tabs, tabbar, ipad

So here goes. I started with a standard out of the box splitview application for iPad. Root view left and detail view to the right. Detail view has it's toolbar at the top.

What I would like to add is a tab bar to the bottom of the detail view and have the tabs load in the details view, between the toolbar tabbar.

Here is the problem, do I add another view between them to load the tabs into, if so how do I get it resize and respect the toolbar and tabbar heights.

Clear?

Hope someone can point me in the right direction. Examples would be great, every example on the web seems to just be out of the box hello world style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the answer is really very simple. UITabBarControllers like SplitViewControllers were intended by Apple to only ever be the Root View Controller and hence you cannot nest a TabBarController in another view, but you can nest a UITabBar in a view, however.

I added the Tabbar to the details view at the bottom, a Navigation bar at the top and then a placeholder view between them. All in Interface Builder!, You will want to switch everything on with the autosize on the Placeholder view.

Next, Implement the UITabBarDelegate. For this you will need:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
```

from that you can use item.tag which if you give each item a unique tag in Interface Builder will let you know which tab the user clicked. I setup defined values for mine:

```
#define VIEW_TAB_A 0
#define VIEW_TAB_B 1
#define VIEW_TAB_C 2
```

Then you will then want to... well best I just let you see

```
    - (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
    [self switchToView:item];
}

- (void) switchToView : (UITabBarItem*) item {

    if( currentViewController != nil ) {
        [currentViewController viewWillDisappear:NO];
        [currentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];               
    }

    switch(item.tag) {
        case VIEW_TAB_A:
            currentViewController = self.viewA;
            break;
        case SCAN_VIEW_TAB_B:
            currentViewController = self.viewB;
            break;
        case PROMOTIONS_VIEW_TAB_C:
            currentViewController = self.viewC;
            break;
    }

    UIView *aView = currentViewController.view; 

    aView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    aView.frame = placeholderView.frame;

    [currentViewController viewWillAppear:NO];

    [self.view insertSubview:aView aboveSubview:placeholderView];
    if( currentViewController != nil ) {
        [currentViewController viewDidDisappear:NO];
    }
    [currentViewController viewDidAppear:NO];
}
```

Remember to alloc the views (viewA, viewB, viewC) first in you viewDidLoad and obviously release in dealloc. Also take note of the autoresizingMask!

Hope this helps others.